# Getting crash due to Check failed in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am passing a data class, which is Serializable, between Activities (say Activity A to Activity B).
Activity B has Jetpack Composable views.
when I Navigate from Activity A to Activity B via a button click, I get the following crash

```
Process: uk.gov.tfl.gotfl, PID: 10022
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check failed.
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateRegistryImpl.performSave(SaveableStateRegistry.kt:150)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.DisposableSaveableStateRegistry_androidKt.DisposableSaveableStateRegistry$lambda-0(DisposableSaveableStateRegistry.android.kt:83)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.DisposableSaveableStateRegistry_androidKt.$r8$lambda$sa5VqeXN41zeUSACzKO7aWvSsug(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.DisposableSaveableStateRegistry_androidKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.saveState(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.performSave(SavedStateRegistry.java:240)
        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController.performSave(SavedStateRegistryController.java:99)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComponentActivity.java:358)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:2169)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1625)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:5680)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:5051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5016)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:5090)
        at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:40)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this crash? I am not doing anything different. It's simple and straightforward.

Comment: Kindly add the code for passing the data and accessing the data.

Answer (score 13):

This is likely caused by using rememberSaveable with a data type that does not implement Serializable. The data needs to be able to be saved to a bundle and if it can't be then you see the "Check failed" error.

Comment: This was the issue at my end. Your answer made sense and saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually caused by [rememberSaveable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) being used with a data type that cannot be innately stored in a Bundle.

A custom class is the typical culprit:

```
data class MyRect(
    val x: Int,
    val y: Int,
    val width: Int,
    val height: Int
)
…
// Throws a IllegalStateException when saved
var rect = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<MyRect?>(null) }
```

To address, either provide a custom [Saver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/Saver), or just make your data class [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable). The latter approach is made easier with the [kotlin-parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) plugin:

```
// In build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
…
@Parcelize
data class MyRect(
    val x: Int,
    val y: Int,
    val width: Int,
    val height: Int
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you attach your compose code? Looking at this crash, it maybe related to the use of rememberSaveable incorrectly.

I had the same crash too. In the end, I replaced rememberSaveable{} with remember{} which temporarily solved it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).